# How to select mutliple rows from a table and pass the selected values to the backend. i am using the MEAN stack for doing this

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, mean

From a table i need to select some rows and pass it to the back end for table how to select particular entries

Comment: Context? What does this have to do with JavaScript? What DBMS are you using? How is your Angular script communicating with the database?

Comment: From the java script i need to select the table contents to json and pass to back end my back end is in Postgresql